# only show lines above some pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

```
git status
On branch a5
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   abc (new commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        058
        a.c
        ...
```

I don't want contents below `Untracked files` line. How to acheive this with regular command grep/perl/sed/awk ?

Comment: `git status --untracked-files=no` ?

Comment: @Paolo OMG, I didn't realize this command exists. It's simplest. But I'm still curious how to acheive this with linux text-filtering command.

Comment: `git status | awk '/Untracked files/ {f=1}{if (!f) {print $0}}'` ?

Comment: `git status | grep -B 100 "Untracked files"`

Comment: You can try like: `git status | awk '/Untracked files/{exit} 1'`

Comment: `git status | sed '/^Untracked files:/,$d'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Untracked files:/Q' file
```

Quit and do not print after a line containing `Untracked files`.